# Watermark CSS not working in Print

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS,

```
#duplicateCopy {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    color:#CCC;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1000; 
    top:35%;
    left:15%;   
    opacity:0.2; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

and also the following div in my html page

```
<div id="duplicateCopy">
<p style="font-size:70px">Duplicate Copy</p>
</div>
```

The above bit of css used to display a water mark in html page. The watermark is working fine in browser window. But while am taking print out the watermark text is not visible. How can i make watermark text visible for print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `media="print"` for this specified CSS or just `media='all'` by writing this CSS in a separate file so that it will also take effect to the print mode. And also make sure that your browser supports CSS3. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" src="css/style.css" />
```

or if you prefer a separate style for printing, simply use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" src="css/print.css" />
```

and write those CSS style into the print.css file.

Comment: I have added @media to that css like
`@media all{
#duplicateCopy {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-20deg);
    transform:rotate(-20deg);
    color:#CCC;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:1000; 
    top:35%;
    left:15%;   
    opacity:0.2; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
}`

But this is not working...

Comment: instead of `@media all` try with `@media print` as @tepkenvannkorn said.